# Proper resistor to drop 24VDC to 12VDC to drive four LEDs in parallel

Tags: power

What is the proper resistor to drop 24VDC to 12VDC to drive 4 LEDs in parallel?

LED specifications:

- Forward current: 10 mA
- Forward voltage: 12 V
- Power rating: 85 mW

[image]

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/423/LTH3MM12VFR4400-1099661.pdf

Comment: You have a LED module; no bare LED is rated for 12V. A series resistor may not be appropriate. What is its manufacturer?  Model number?  Please attach some pictures.

Comment: The LTH3MM12VFR4400 datasheet says it is not a bare LED but a module with integrated resistor. You should edit your post with a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 3):

The other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695674/101063) notes that if the LED modules are 12 V rated they probably have an internal series resistor.

**Update**: The question has been edited to give the part number of the LEDs as LTH3MM12VFR4400. The [datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/423/LTH3MM12VFR4400-1099661.pdf) describes this as having a built-in resistor:

> LTH3MM12V Series 3mm (T-1) Through Hole LED **Built in Resistor** for 12VDC

And the characteristics show approx 11 mA for a 12 V forward voltage:

[image]

The following suggestion is thus still valid.

Given four 12 V modules, and a 24 V supply, perhaps a 2-parallel 2-series combination of LED modules is simpler, and avoids the need for an additional series resistor (which wastes power as heat). Where each LED module will has 10 mA current through it and 12 V across it, as shown in the following simulation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwtRde.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Not modules bare led's see update for more detail

Comment: @ezflyer123 On checking the datasheet, a internal series resistor **is** described as being present. Have updated my answer, which doesn't change the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If they really are 12V rated, then they are modules with built-in resistors. The internal resistor will be about 1k.

Your series resistor will need to drop 12 volts at 40 mA. 12/0.04 = 300 ohms. The power dissipated will be about 1/2 Watt. If you run a resistor near its rating it will get really hot, don't do that. I wouldn't use less than a 1 Watt.

If you are unsure, put a voltmeter across the LED modules, then start with a larger value resistor. Lower the value until the voltage is about 12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhc1h5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>